# How to make listview reorder itself when item is inserted

Tags: android, listview, insert

I have a list view in which I can insert items(the items are inserted in the database). The problem is that when I insert an item, it shows at the bottom of the list. How can I make it go to the right position? The items should in alphabetical order. If I exit the app and enter, the inserted item is at the right position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changes to DB like inserting / updating / deleting you need to call requery() to your cursor, e.g. `dbCursor.requery();`

Answer (score 0):

you can do array sort with alphabets and then assign to listview so it will display alphabets display.